# Entrance exam probability problem

Tags: probability

Suppose that a fair coin is tossed until a head appears. Given that the coin is tossed four times and no head is obtained in these four tosses, what is the probability that the coin must be tossed at least two more times to obtain the first head?

I am getting 1/2 as my answer and I want to cross check my answer. Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: That’s correct. It’s just the probability that the next flip is tails, which is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Please create a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, correct.

The possible results in the next 2 tosses are

- TT
- TH
- HT
- HH

Thus the only 2 favourable events are the first two, with a total probability 0.5

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need at least two more tosses to get a head means that the fifth toss is again a tail, so
$$P(\text{at least two tosses for a head}\mid \text{four tails})=P(\text{the fifth is tail}\mid \text{four tails})=P(\text{the fifth is tail})=0.5,$$

since the fifth toss is independent of the first four.